# android compose ime not change when focus of textfield move to other textfield

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Ime doesn't change when focus of textfield move to other textfield.

I have two text field like below.

```kotlin
var myValue by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
// A TextField
TextField(
    value = myValue,
    onValueChange = { myValue = it },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Search))

// B TextField
TextField(
    value = myValue,
    onValueChange = { myValue = it },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Next))
```

First,When I click A for the first time and the keyboard comes up, ime is well set to search. In this state, if I click B to move the focus to B, the IME is still Search.

When I put down the keyboard and click B, the IME is fine set to Next.

Whenever I click on the text field, I want it to be reflected immediately in the set ime every time. What should I do?